# Store Image name in text view

Tags: java, android, android-bitmap, url-encoding, bitmapimage

This is my code for storing image in ImageView but i want to store image name in My TextView Object Please help how to do this.

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            filePath = data.getData();
            try {

                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

MainActivity.java

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


    public static final String UPLOAD_URL = "http://192.168.1.101:8080/ImageUpload/upload2.php";
    public static final String UPLOAD_KEY = "image";
    public static final String TAG = "MY MESSAGE";

    private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private Button buttonChoose;
    private Button buttonUpload;
    private Button buttonView;


    private ImageView imageView;

    private Bitmap bitmap;

    //private Uri filePath;
    private static Uri filePath;
    private TextView tv1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonChoose = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonChoose);
        buttonUpload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonUpload);
        buttonView = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonViewImage);

        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

        buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonUpload.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

            filePath = data.getData();
            try {

                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), filePath);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public String getStringImage(Bitmap bmp){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
        byte[] imageBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(imageBytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
        return encodedImage;
    }

    private void uploadImage(){
        class UploadImage extends AsyncTask<Bitmap,Void,String> {

            ProgressDialog loading;
            RequestHandler rh = new RequestHandler();

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loading = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Uploading Image", "Please wait...",true,true);
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                loading.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
                Bitmap bitmap = params[0];
                String uploadImage = getStringImage(bitmap);

                HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<>();
                data.put(UPLOAD_KEY, uploadImage);

                String result = rh.sendPostRequest(UPLOAD_URL,data);

                return result;
            }
        }

        UploadImage ui = new UploadImage();
        ui.execute(bitmap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == buttonChoose) {
            showFileChooser();
        }
        if(v == buttonUpload){
            uploadImage();
        }
    }
    }
```

RequestHandler.java

```
public class RequestHandler {

    public String sendGetRequest(String uri) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(uri);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

            String result;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while((result = bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                sb.append(result);
            }

            return sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String sendPostRequest(String requestURL,
                                  HashMap<String, String> postDataParams) {

        URL url;
        String response = "";
        try {
            url = new URL(requestURL);

            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setReadTimeout(15000);
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(getPostDataString(postDataParams));

            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

            if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
                response = br.readLine();
            } else {
                response = "Error Registering";
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return response;
    }

    private String getPostDataString(HashMap<String, String> params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        boolean first = true;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : params.entrySet()) {
            if (first)
                first = false;
            else
                result.append("&");

            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            result.append("=");
            result.append(URLEncoder.encode(entry.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
        }

        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

[image]

When i clicked on choose file it take me to gallery for selecting an image file now from here i want that when i selected image the name of image shows in my textview please describe me how to do this.

Comment: what do you mean by 'image name'?

Comment: Thanks For Replying Hamid Reza, Button ImageView This is my current Layout to upload Image to server But now I want to upload image to server in this layout Button TextView, So to complete this i want the reference of selected image in my TextView.

Comment: So just store `filePath` and `encodedImage` inside static object and use it any where!

Answer (score 0):

Try below code,hope that it's works for you

You can get file name from URI using below code :

```
File file = getFile(context,filePath);
String imageName = file.getName();
TextView.setText(imageName);
```

here is the getFile function,

```
public static File getFile(Context context, Uri uri) {
        if (uri != null) {
            String path = getPath(context, uri);
            if (path != null && isLocal(path)) {
                return new File(path);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I interpreted that you want the image name, so here is a code to get the image name from the path you have.
Rather you can store all the image name and path in a separate hashmap and can get any image name with the corresponding image path later.

```
public static String getImages(Context context) {
                Uri uri;
                Cursor cursor;
                int column_index_data, column_index_file_name;
                String PathOfImage = null;
                uri = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

                String[] projection = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA,
                        MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE };
                //get you a cursor with which you can search all images in your device
                cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null,
                        null, null);
                //get the column index of the Path of the image
                column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA);
                //get the column index of the name of the image
                column_index_file_name = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE);
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    PathOfImage = cursor.getString(column_index_data);
                    String name = cursor.getString(column_index_file_name);
                    Log.e("Manojit",PathOfImage+"\n"+name);

                    if(PathOfImage.equals(filepath)){
    //here you will get the title of the image
    //from the result set the content of the Textview
                        return cursor.getString(column_index_file_name);}
                }
                return null;
            }
```

Comment: I used you code to show image name in TextView But It not working.

Comment: i am going to share my activity and xml files please check and give me solution.Manojit Paul

Comment: if the image you are working is in your device, then this code will work.